# How to show that this function $f(x,y,) <0$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I would like to show that the function $f(x,y) = -5 x^4 + 4 y^2 - 5 y^4 + x^2 (4 - 6 y^2)$ is less than $0$ for $1 < x^2 + y^2 <2$ (at least). Upon rearranging, I obtain

$f(x,y) = -5(x^2+y^2)^2 + 4(x^2 +y^2 + x^2y^2)$

But then I don't know how to proceed to get $f(x,y)<0?

Thanks!

Comment: If I'm not making a mistake, $f(1/2,1/2)=1>0$ while $0<1/2^2+1/2^2=1/2<2$

Comment: so then the question is outright wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $1 < x^{2} +y^{2} < 2$! @NathanielB

Answer (score 4):

Let us write this expression under the form:

$$f(x,y) = -5(x^2+y^2)^2 + 4(x^2 +y^2) + 4 x^2y^2$$

Let us convert this expression into polar coordinates. One gets:

$$F(r,\theta) = -5r^4 + 4r^2 + r^4 \sin ^2(2 \theta)$$

(using relationship $\sin (2 \theta) = 2 \sin \theta \cos \theta$).

Therefore:

$$F(r,\theta) = r^2 (r^2 (\sin ^2(2 \theta) - 5) + 4)$$

For $r>0$, the sign of $F$ is that of $g(r,\theta):=r^2 (\sin^2(2 \theta) - 5) + 4$

Let $1<r^2<2 \ \ \ (1) $. Taking into consideration that

$0-5 \leq \sin^2(2 \theta) - 5 \leq -4 \ \ \ (2)$

Multiplication of (1) by (2) gives:

$$-5 \leq r^2 (\sin^2(2 \theta) - 5) \leq -4$$

Adding 4 to the three parts gives the result: $-1 \leq g(r,\theta) \leq 0$.

Comment: Sorry, mistake! Made a quick computer plot with an inaccurate scale - hence the wrong conclusion...

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the first version of my answer which was not answering satisfactorily your question.

Comment: Shouldn't the last term be $r^4\sin^2(2\theta)$?

Comment: My bad, you are right. I correct it now.

Comment: I think that now, at last, I propose a convenient answer...

Comment: Thank you very much, @egreg for your remark.